# Entity provider not working in security.yml php symfony3.4 ({"code":401,"message":"bad credentials"}.)

Tags: php, mongodb, authentication, jwt, symfony-3.4

I'm using symfony 3.4 with DoctrineMongoDBBundle and LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle . I'm trying to create a user login which return JWT token. If i specify the username and password under in_memory provider, it returns the token but if i use a entity provider, it returns {"code":401,"message":"bad credentials"}.

Here is my security.yml

```html
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html
security:

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Document\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 12

    providers:  
            webprovider:
                entity:
                    class: AppBundle\Document\User
                    property: username

    firewalls:

        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        
        login:

            pattern:  ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            provider: webprovider
            form_login:
                username_parameter: username
                password_parameter: password
                check_path:               /api/login_check
                success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                require_previous_session: false

        api:
            pattern:   ^/api
            stateless: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
    

        main:
            anonymous: ~
            # activate different ways to authenticate

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate
            #http_basic: ~

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html
            #form_login: ~
    



    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Here is my User class

```html
<?php

// /AppBundle/Document/User.php
namespace AppBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\Validator\Constraints\Unique as MongoDBUnique;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
/**
 * @MongoDB\Document(collection="users")
 * @MongoDBUnique(fields="email")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{


    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    protected $email;
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $username;
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $password;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    public function __construct()
    {
        var_dump("1");
        $this->isActive = true;
        // may not be needed, see section on salt below
        // $this->salt = md5(uniqid('', true));
    }

    public function getId()
    {

        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        var_dump($this->username);  
        return $this->username;
    }
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return null;
    }
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array('ROLE_USER');
    }
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

}
```

Would really appreciate if someone could help, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should use FOS bundle components by extending Base model User calss in entity, better than using directly Implementing UserInterface, In your case problem could be your password is not getting encoded correct. It's better to encode using `security.password_encoder`. To more better understanding i am sharing an example to setup login and generating token.

Your security.yml should look like this

```
`# Symfony 3.4 security.yml
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext



    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
        ROLE_API:         ROLE_USER, ROLE_MEDIC, ROLE_STUDENT



    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

        in_memory:
            memory: ~



    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false


        api_login:
            pattern:  ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            form_login:
                check_path:               /api/login_check
                success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                require_previous_session: false

        api:
            pattern:  ^/(api)
            stateless: true  #false (not assign cookies)
            anonymous: ~
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
                provider: fos_userbundle


    access_control: .................`
```

Your User class should be like this:

```
// /AppBundle/Document/User.php
namespace AppBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\Validator\Constraints\Unique as MongoDBUnique;
/**
 * @MongoDB\Document(collection="users")
 * @MongoDBUnique(fields="email")
 */
class User implements BaseUser
{


    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    protected $email;
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $username;
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $password;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    public function __construct()
    {
        var_dump("1");
        $this->isActive = true;
        // may not be needed, see section on salt below
        // $this->salt = md5(uniqid('', true));
    }

    public function getId()
    {

        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        var_dump($this->username);  
        return $this->username;
    }
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return null;
    }
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array('ROLE_USER');
    }
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

}
```

Now your Api tokenController.php to generate token and validate token

```
namespace \your_namespace\Api;

use FOS\RestBundle\Context\Context;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;


use AppBundle\Document\User;
# Below most of the components belongs to Nelmio api or Sensio or Symfony
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactory;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Exception\ExpiredTokenException;
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Exception\InvalidTokenException;
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Exception\JWTDecodeFailureException;
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Security\Authentication\Token\PreAuthenticationJWTUserToken;

use Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\Annotation\ApiDoc;


    class TokenController extends FOSRestController
    {
        /**
         * @Rest\Post("/tokens", name="api_token_new",
         *     options={"method_prefix" = false},
         *     defaults={"_format"="json"}
         * )
         *
         * @ApiDoc(
         *    section     = "Security",
         *    description = "Get user token",
         *    parameters={
         *      {"name"="username", "dataType"="string", "required"=true, "description"="username or email"},
         *      {"name"="pass",     "dataType"="string", "required"=true, "description"="password "},
         *    }
         * )
         */
        public function newTokenAction(Request $request)
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $username = $request->get('username');
            /** @var User $user */
            $user = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findOneBy(['email' => $username]);
            if (!$user) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException();
            }
            if (!$user->isEnabled()){
                throw $this->createNotFoundException($this->get('translator')->trans('security.user_is_disabled'));
            }


            $pass = $request->get('pass');
            $isValid = $this->get('security.password_encoder')->isPasswordValid($user, $pass);
            if (!$isValid) {
                throw new BadCredentialsException();
            }

            $token = $this->get('lexik_jwt_authentication.encoder')->encode([
                'username' => $user->getUsername(),
                'id'       => $user->getId(),
                'roles'    => $user->getRoles(),
                'exp'      => time() + (30 * 24 * 3600) // 30 days expiration -> move to parameters or config
            ]);


            // Force login
            $tokenLogin = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $pass, "public", $user->getRoles());
            $this->get("security.token_storage")->setToken($tokenLogin);

            // Fire the login event
            // Logging the user in above the way we do it doesn't do this automatically
            $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $tokenLogin);
            $this->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);

            $view = $this->view([
                'token' => $token,
                'user'  => $user
            ]);
            $context = new Context();
            $context->addGroups(['Public']);
            $view->setContext($context);

            return $this->handleView($view);
        }


         /**
 * @Rest\Post("/validate", name="api_token_validate",
 *     options={"method_prefix" = false},
 *     defaults={"_format"="json"}
 * )
 *
 * @ApiDoc(
 *    section     = "Security",
 *    description = "Get user by token",
 *    parameters={
 *      {"name"="token", "dataType"="textarea", "required"=true, "description"="token"},
 *    }
 * )
 */
public function validateUserToken(Request $request)
{
    $token = $request->get('token');
    //get UserProviderInterface
    $fos  = $this->get('fos_user.user_provider.username_email');
    //create PreAuthToken
    $preAuthToken = new PreAuthenticationJWTUserToken($token);
    try {
        if (!$payload = $this->get('lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_manager')->decode($preAuthToken)) {
            throw new InvalidTokenException('Invalid JWT Token');
        }
        $preAuthToken->setPayload($payload);
    } catch (JWTDecodeFailureException $e) {
        if (JWTDecodeFailureException::EXPIRED_TOKEN === $e->getReason()) {
            throw new ExpiredTokenException();
        }
        throw new InvalidTokenException('Invalid JWT Token', 0, $e);
    }
    //get user
    /** @var User $user */
    $user = $this->get('lexik_jwt_authentication.security.guard.jwt_token_authenticator')->getUser($preAuthToken, $fos);
    $view = $this->view([
        'token' => $token,
        'user'  => $user
    ]);
    $context = new Context();
    $context->addGroups(array_merge(['Public'],$user->getRoles()));
    $view->setContext($context);
    return $this->handleView($view);
}
```

if you face any problem then , let me know.

Comment: Hi, I have tried your code, I'm getting an exception in "validateUserToken" method :

"The first argument of the \"Lexik\\Bundle\\JWTAuthenticationBundle\\Security\\Guard\\JWTTokenAuthenticator::getUser()\" method must be an instance of \"Lexik\\Bundle\\JWTAuthenticationBundle\\Security\\Authentication\\Token\\PreAuthenticationJWTUserToken\".",

Comment: Hi @KiranKumar can you try with new changes , also don't forget to install lexik bundle. If you face still any problem let me know in comments.

Comment: Hi @Ashutosh, thank you so much. everything is working fine. May I know how could I implement 'Logout' functionality in this way...

Comment: If you need I can help you in writing logout logic.

Comment: here is logic to logout: 
`public function logoutAction(Request $request)
    {
        $this->get('app.user')->expireSession();
        return new JsonResponse('Server Logout');
    }`

Comment: what does $request object contains and how this logic clears a session of particular user ?

Comment: @KiranKumar i can't write here in comment this logic is little long , so adding another answer to handle the logout

Comment: HI @KiranKumar, i had a demo repo on github https://github.com/ashurai/sfdemo3.4, you can check only `/Manager`, and service config `/resources/config/service.yml` and `/controller/api/TokenCOntroller.php`, if you have some confusion please comment on the git repos, i think that will help you understand more. if you have any problem then please open an issue and i will help you on that.

Comment: I am getting "You have requested a non-existent service "app.manager.user" in logoutAction() method. How to resolve this. I have tried your demo app code, plz help me.

Comment: @AshutoshRai in your demo in the `expireSession()` in `UserManager.php`, you delete the cookie, but where are you setting it first and what are you using the cookie for?

Comment: @AshutoshRai i dont know php, but i think what you are `set`ting in `UserManager.php` is set in `services.yml`. On logging out in `expireSession()`, you are calling `$this->security->setToken(null);` and deleting cookie but in `validateUserToken()` you are not using cookie or the token set in `services.yml`. please tell me where you are setting the token and how you are invalidating it

Comment: @Dwigh for a better understanding please read this document https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security.html

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the provider before json_login tag this the case for me

```
    provider: fos_userbundle
```